# Regexp plurals - how?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect two versions of the same thing, plural and now

eg:

"piece" and "pieces" should both return a match.

```
var re_1 = new RegExp("how many piece", "i");
```

or

```
var re_1 = new RegExp("how many pieces", "i");
```

How do I form a RegExp expression in Javascript to detect both singular and plural in the same pattern?

Comment: Don't forget about man/men, ox/oxen, child/children, axis/axes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> /how many pieces?/.test('how many piece')
true
>>> /how many pieces?/.test('how many pieces')
true
>>> /how many pieces?/.test('how many piecez')
true
>>> /how many pieces?/.test('how many piec')
false
```

The question mark denotes that the prior character is optional. You shouldn't need to construct a `new RegExp` unless you're dynamically generating it, feel free to add any additional options after the end `/` ( g for global, i for case insensitive ).

Comment: This wouldn't work very well for words that need "es" instead of just "s" (box->boxes) as well as y->ies (delivery->deliveries), and countless other examples.